# Make td expand to max width before text wraps

Tags: html, css

I feel like there's a simple way to do this, but I just can't think of/find a solution...

I have a `<table>` that that should scroll-x if it overflows (which it's expected to) The `<td>` elements are set to `max-width: 300px`. I want the text in the `<td>` to wrap ONLY AFTER the `<td>` has hit the max-width. Right now text is wrapping as soon as the `<table>` doesn't fit its parent `<div>`.

How can I make the `<td>` expand to its max width before the text wraps?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ds99unpz/2/

EDIT: to clarify...

If the td doesn't have to be 300px wide to fit the text on one line, I don't want it to be 300px. If the text is too long to fit in a 300px td, THEN I want the td to be 300px wide and the text to wrap.

Comment: Code Please! Create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or feed us with some code.

Comment: Add your table HTML and relevant CSS to the question please!

Answer (score 1):

I [updated your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds99unpz/43/).  It coerces the tables and cells to act like `block`'s and `inline-block`'s, respectively.  Then using a little `white-space: nowrap;` magic and forcing the `table` to overflow, we get the desired result.  However, the cells aren't all the same height.

Comment: You can set vertical-alignment in the `td` an `th` to make them line up in a consistent way. Great job, @divinecomedian !

Comment: It's close, but take a look what happens if you have more than one row. Columns don't align. https://jsfiddle.net/ds99unpz/45/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   
}
table{
    
    height: 150px;
    
}
td {
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

EDIT:,

Added `style="white-space: nowrap"` to `<td>`

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

CSS:

```
.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
table{

    height: 150px;

}
td {
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds99unpz/41/)

Or all css

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

CSS:

```
.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
table{

    height: 150px;

}
td {
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds99unpz/42/)

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` "...only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells".
If the text is smaller than 300px, I want the td to shrink accordingly. If it's longer than 300px, I want it to use the 300px BEFORE wrapping.

Comment: check the fiddle. place your <div> tag within the <td> tag. https://jsfiddle.net/ds99unpz/25/

Comment: still not what I'm looking for. Individual cells shouldn't scroll. Please re-read the question and ask for clarification if necessary.